# Would C/C++ code compiling on Mingw guarantee full compatibility with GCC(on linux and Mac)

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, compatibility

I'd like to produce cross-compiler compatible C++ code.
I've produced a somewhat "exotic" code, that push the C++ language in its gray, weird, mysterious areas.

Considering my code only depends on boost and the STL, that the issue is to check code compatibility, and not lib compatibility:

Would my code compiling both msvc and Mingw ensures a 100% that my code is compatible with GCC on every platform?

Comment: What do you mean by "every platform"? There are many, many platforms in existence and even more obsolete ones. You should target a subset of them all and do your testing there. Only then can you be sure that your code is closs platform compatible.

Comment: By "Platform", I mean "target processors". My guess was that the way GCC compiles is aways the same on a given instruction set, independently to the OS.

Comment: There is no such thing as grey areas. It is either well defined (in which case it will work cross platform). Or it is implementation defined (in which case read the compiler docs for what that means) Or it is undefined (which means the behavior may change by increasing the optimization level). If you have undefined behavior you can not even gurantee the same behavior between builds so that is definately not gray it is just pure black. You could argue that implementation defined is  grey but these are well documented and you should know when it happens (as the compiler will spew warnings).

Comment: @Martin: Undefined does not mean that at all. Undefined behaviour means OMGWTFBBQAAAAAAAAHPROGRAMCRASH on most modern OSes, or nothing at all, or everything in between, concurrently if necessary. In addition to demons magically spawning inside your nose.

Comment: @Martin except the compilers discussed are not 100% standard compliant so that reasoning doesn't hold, it may be well defined but it doesn't mean everyone implements it properly

Comment: @DeadMG: No. It means exactly what it says. Its undefined by the standard. In a lot of situations this means it crashes in a lot it will mysteriously do nothing bad. Change the optimization level on the compiler and potentially the behavior will change (because it is not defined to do anything particular).

Comment: @jk: You have to have a minimum set of assumptions that hold otherwise you could not make any statements. PS. I don't take into account stray x-rays that might strike your memory either and flip the bits Nor do I worry about noisy power supply systems where the static could cause the memory bus to fail. If it fails to meet the standard it is a compiler bug. In 30 years I have only hit 2 and both of those were over a decade ago (gcc prior to 2.95) and one of those turned out to be me not the compiler.

Comment: @Martin York: Undefined behaviour does not mean "changes by optimization level", it means undefined. It may change by absolutely anything else, or not at all.

Comment: @DeadMG: Read my comment more carefully as you seem to be twisting my words into something else (or don't understand them). Undefined means it is undefined. That means its behavior **can** change with optimization level (because the behavior is undefined). And often does. `<quote>Change the optimization level on the compiler and potentially the behavior will change</quote>`. Try a double delete in debug and a double delete in optimized code. I bet you will see different behavior under dev studio. Optimized code it will probably crash (though it may not) debug code it probably will not crash.

Comment: @Martin: I think it's you that doesn't understand me. I'm perfectly happy to accept that undefined behaviour DOES change with optimization level. However, that's not exactly the critical aspect of undefined behaviour, is it? Stating that undefined behaviour changes with opt level is missing the planet for the pebble.

Comment: @DeadMG: I see. We will just have to leave it there. Please practice reading :-) It will do you good for future pointless flames. :-p

Comment: How do you define "'exotic' code, that push the C++ language in its gray, weird, mysterious areas"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all.

Compiling your code with MSVC and MinGW guarantees that your code is compatible with Microsoft's C/C++ libraries. I understand you're only talking about code compatibility, but such a thing doesn't exist. If you're pushing C++ into the gray areas, it might well be that the same code will have different results depending on the platform you compile it on.

The best, and only way to guarantee full compatibility is compiling and testing it on both platforms.

Although using GCC with `-std=c++0X -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (or any other std version) and getting rid of all the warnings will give a pretty good idea of code quality.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly? To guarantee your code will compile with GCC on any platform is impossible. There is always that likelihood that something could be off, especially if you are doing 'exotic' things with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try compiling with cygwin, which would give a better idea of how it will build on a more Unix like system (although it's still not guaranteed to work on all systems, but it's better than just trying msvc and MingW which are both just windows compilers).